# Octave - error reading data with textscan function

Tags: octave, textscan

I am trying to read data of the following format with textscan:

```
date,location,new_cases,new_deaths,total_cases,total_deaths
2019-12-31,Afghanistan,0,0,0,0
2020-01-01,Afghanistan,0,0,0,0
2020-01-02,Afghanistan,0,0,0,0
2020-01-03,Afghanistan,0,0,0,0
2020-01-04,Afghanistan,0,0,0,0
...
```

(Full data file available here: https://covid.ourworldindata.org/data/ecdc/full_data.csv)

My code is:

```
# Whitespace replaced with _
file_name = "full_data.csv"; 
fid = fopen(file_name, "rt");
data= textscan(fid, "%s%s%d%d%d%d", "Delimiter", ",", "HeaderLines", 1, ...
  "ReturnOnError", 0);
fclose(fid);
```

Text scan terminates with an error:

```
error: textscan: Read error in field 3 of row 421
```

Row 421 is the center row in the example below:

```
2020-01-12,Australia,0,0,0,0
2020-01-13,Australia,0,0,0,0
2020-01-14,Australia,0,0,0,0
2020-01-15,Australia,0,0,0,0
2020-01-16,Australia,0,0,0,0
2020-01-17,Australia,0,0,0,0
2020-01-18,Australia,0,0,0,0
```

I've checked the row it complains about and there is nothing different from the example above. I've replaced all spaces in the file with underscores too. Am I doing something wrong with textcan?

Comment: Are you using MATLAB it Octave? Please crop your input file to a few lines around the offending one, verify you still get the error, and then copy-paste that file into your question, along with the minimal code to reproduce the error. This is the only way we can help you fund out what is going on. See [mre].

Comment: I'm using Octave. I've updated the question to include the sample around the reported error line, and also update the example code plus added a link to full date file.

Comment: I tried both MATLAB (2013) and Octave (4.2), they both work fine. what version of octave are you using?

Comment: I'm using Octave 4.2.1

Comment: The practical answer to your question is, don't use textscan. Use csv2cell instead. Textscan is unnecessarily complicated and you're dealing with simple csv files. See my answer to your previous question for an example.